# Change the structure of nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I m trying to change the structure of the json file. Below is the function that is being used for the current structure. I m trying to change the current function so the right and left key of the json will be merged as child. However, I m facing difficulty with it. Can you guys help me to modify the code or suggest an efficient way to perform the function?

```
var buildTree = function(jsonObj){

      if(!jsonObj)
          return;
      for(var n in jsonObj){
          that.topicList.push(n);
          return{
                key : n,
                right : buildTree(jsonObj[n][0]),
                left : buildTree(jsonObj[n][1])
          }
      }
  }
```

The input for this code:

```
{
"math": [{
    "Math": []
}, {
    "A Greek–English Lexicon": [{
        "A-list": []
    }, {
        "ASCII": []
    }]
}]
}
```

Current output:

```
{
"key": "math",
"right": {
    "key": "Math"
},
"left": {
    "key": "A Greek–English Lexicon",
    "right": {
        "key": "A-list"
    },
    "left": {
        "key": "ASCII"
    }
}
}
```

I want to change the above output into the one like below:

```
{
"name": "math",
"child": [
  {
    "name": "Math",
    "children" :[]
},
{
    "name": "A Greek–English Lexicon",
    "child": [
      {
        "name": "A-list",
        "child" : []
        },
        {
        "name": "ASCII",
        "child" : []
        }
    ]
}
]}
```

Comment: please add the original object.

Comment: Please can you edit the question to add the input for this? it will make it easier to visualize what the code is doing now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive approach, which returns a new object.

```js
var object = { "math": [{ "Math": [] }, { "A Greek–English Lexicon": [{ "A-list": [] }, { "ASCII": [] }] }] },
    newObject = {};

function restyle(obj) {
    var k = Object.keys(obj)[0];
    return {
        key: k,
        child: obj[k].map(restyle)
    };
};

newObject = restyle(object);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newObject, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

This is a recursive approach, which changes the object *in situ*.

```js
function restyle(o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        o.key = k;
        o.child = o[k];
        delete o[k];
        o.child.forEach(restyle);
    });
};

var object = { "math": [{ "Math": [] }, { "A Greek–English Lexicon": [{ "A-list": [] }, { "ASCII": [] }] }] };
restyle(object);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Your answer is specific and not generic for all inputs

Comment: @prajnavantha, what do you mean by *specific*?

Comment: Oops sorry there mate... I didn see the code output properly before commenting. It works fine and even shorter and better then my version.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a solution for this. You basically need to do recursive programming. You may need to do some basic changes if there are errors but essentially i've written the logic and the code. 
It will recursively parse through the child elements until it finds an empty array, i.e the leaf node. Im assuming there will always be only two child since it looked like a simple tree.

```
            /*Initially the object is pased here*/
            function parse(obj){
                /*Im assuming that the object has a key and value you need to add other failure checks here*/
                var keys =Object.keys(obj)
                return {
                    "name": keys[0]
                    "child" getChilds(obj[keys[0]])
                }
            }

            /*This is a recursive function which will grab left and right child and finally return the output.*/
            function getChilds(arr){


                    if(arr.length === 0){
                        return []
                    }
                    var obj = arr[0]
                    var keys =Object.keys(obj)


                    var newObj = {}
                    /*left child*/
                    var left = {
                        "name":keys[0],
                        "child":getChilds( obj[keys[0]] )
                    }

                    var obj = arr[1]
                    var keys =Object.keys(obj)
                    /*right child*/
                    var right = {
                        "name":keys[0],
                        "child":getChilds( obj[keys[0]] )
                    }

                    return [left,right]


            }
```